# Android changing date in a specific EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have implemented the android DatepickerDialog. The DatepickerDialog fires when the user clicks on a EditText.

[image]

Sample of my Layout code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etDate1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="+ Add Date"
    android:onClick="selectDate" />
```

Following is the Code used to get the DatepickerDialog to work.

```
public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {     
    etDate1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate1);
    etDate1.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);

    etDate2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate2);
    etDate2.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
}
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I click one of these EditText the DatePicker will appear and when I select a specific date from the datepicker, it gets applied for both EditTexts shown above. I need it to be only one. It would be great if someone could provide me a solution for this.

Comment: Because your populateSetDate function does set the date values to both EditTexts. comment one and you will find the date population will happen to only one EditText.

Comment: @AstralProjection I need the date to be populated only on the clicked EditText. Both EditText needs to be clickable.

Comment: Its about which value you want to set to which view, put a flag and check if your first had been clicked and if the value DatePicker returns is intended for that view.

Comment: @onefourone14 the solution is pretty simple. Just pass the `id` of the clicked view as I have explained in my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code as follows:

```
public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment(view.getId());
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day, int viewId) {
    etDate1 = (EditText) findViewById(viewId);
    etDate1.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
}
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private final int viewId;

    public SelectDateFragment(int viewId) {
        this.viewId = viewId;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd, viewId);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** Pass the `id` of the view being clicked, to the dialog. When the date is selected, pass this `id` back, and populate the correct `EditText` which is having this `id`

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are calling the method selectDate(View) onTouch or onClick of the Edittext and parameter passed is Edittext, giving you the solution.

Step #1: Declare a class variable of type Edittext. (Used to save the refrence of edittext which has been touched)

Step #2: Initialize above the variable inside the SelectDate(View).

Step #3: Replace the code block inside the populateSetDate(), with assigning text to that class variable declared at step 1.

Just to mention, this is not Android related quest!!

Comment: I'm kind of new to this. It would really appreciate if you could provide me a sample code.

Comment: Post your onTouch/onClick code.. @Amulya Khare code block is correct.